# undefined after ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax function that returns data and I want to push the `objects` name into an array but when I check the console, it keeps saying undefined. How can I print the certain attribute only?

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/list',
      type: 'get',
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.name);
      },
      error: function(){
        console.log('err');
      }
    });
```

When I check the results on console

```
//console.log(response);
(3) [{...}, {...}, {...}]
1: {_id: "1", name: "a"}
2: {_id: "2", name: "b"}
3: {_id: "3", name: "c"}

//console.log(response.name);
(3)undefined
```

Comment: response[0].name // for first object name the output array

Answer (score 2):

Your response is an object so you must identify the index of what you want to display

```
  console.log(response[1].name); //will display "b"
```

Comment: You mean _"array"_, not _"object"_

Comment: `response` is an `array` (which in JS is an object, but still not what you wanted to say).

Comment: silly me, thx! I will take this as an answer after a few mins

Answer (score 1):

Your result is in the form of `array of objects` so `console.log(response.name);` will not work for you. You've to add the index e.g `response[1]` and then `property` name like `response[1].name` to get the name of 2nd element, See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to see more about **Property Accessors**

```
response[0].name // logs a
response[1].name // logs b
response[2].name // logs c
```

**e.g**

```js
const response = [{_id: "1", name: "a"},{_id: "2", name: "b"},{_id: "3", name: "c"}]

console.log(response[2].name);
```

Comment: Nice example illustrating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 3 objects each with a name, did you want to output all of them?

```js
const response = [{_id: "1", name: "a"},{_id: "2", name: "b"},{_id: "3", name: "c"}];
console.log(response.map(({name})=>name).join());
// or one at a time
response.forEach(({name}, index)=>console.log(`${index}: "${name}"`));
```